# How to or is it necessary to define types of attributes in a class in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, types, attributes

I am quite new at python and I have some questions regarding the type of an attribute in a class. From experience with C, I got this sense that you should always define the type of a variable right when you create it, yet in Python it seems not.

I am trying to create a class with 3 attributes. Using Python 3.7 in Pycharm.

One way is to do it like this

```
class Solution:
        next: int
        f_star: tuple
        t_star: list
```

Another way is like this

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.next = int
        self.f_star = tuple
       self.t_star = list
```

But none of them really limits the attributes to the according type. I can still execute say

```
node = Solution
node.t_star = 5
```

Then I run this to test what is the type of attributes before assigning a new value. So I did this:

```
node = Solution
print(type(node.next))
```

In the first case it returns the type correctly < class, 'int'> but in the second case, it says

```
AttributeError: type object 'Solution' has no attribute 'f_star'.
```

Could anyone please explain why there is such a difference and what is the difference in the two ways defining a class.

And how to or is it necessary to define the type of attributes in a class in python?

Answer (score -1):

One of the main points of Python, partly to try to make it easier for beginners, also to make it easier to read, is you don't need to declare variable types. It has "duck typing" (google it), and is not statically typed. The same variable can change from an integer to a float to a string in fact, which has disadvantages and advantages.

Comment: Thanks, I found that python is called a dynamic typing of programming languages, but what about the difference between those two ways to define the attributes, why they yield such results?

Comment: what difference are you talking about exactly? Your question gives both with same class name, it's difficult to understand. Also, next is a keyword in Python, don't name an attribute next.

Comment: Without setting a value to node.next, if I simply run 'node = Solution
print(type(node.next))', the first type of difination will return the type correctly < class, 'int'> but in the second case(the one using __init__), it says AttributeError: type object 'Solution' has no attribute 'f_star'.